# How to iterate values and display in label in lightning?

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I have one component in lightning where i am fetching names of products from object and i want to display that names as list one below another. I know we can use for loop but can you please share example of how to iterate names?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can always use `<aura:iteration>` [iteration help](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/ref_tag_iteration.htm)

Comment: Thanks Manjit. Can you please share one example of the same?

Comment: Hi Sofiya, The link that is shared in first comment contains an example. If you run into any specific issue, please let me know.

Answer (score 2):

Below Are Code In That I Iterate  Contact Object List.

Showing All Contact List Hope This Helpful for you.

```
<ul>
        <aura:iteration items="{!v.contacts}" var="contact">
            <li>
                <a href="{! '#/sObject/' + contact.Id + '/view'}">
                    <p>{!contact.Name}</p>
                    <p>{!contact.Phone}</p>
                </a>
            </li>
        </aura:iteration>
    </ul>
```